# How can I use one SQL login or connection string for Alembic and a different one for SQL Alchemy?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

My company has given me two SQL Logins, let's call them `app_rw` and `app_owner`. `app_rw` has `db_writer` permissions and `app_owner` has `db_owner` permissions. `app_rw` cannot create tables, and `app_owner` shouldn't be used to fetch data.

I currently am building a Flask app which has the `DATABASE_URL` set in an environment variable. My Docker entrypoint looks like this,

```bash
# upgrade the db before running the app
flask db upgrade head

# run the app
gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 'app:create_app()'
```

But, this always uses the same login in the connection string in my environment variable for both the migrations and the app.

How can I run alembic as `app_owner` and the app as `app_rw`?

Comment: Yes,assuming all the permissions are ok.  Have you tried?

Comment: Specifically I'm wondering how I can use two connection strings: one for Alembic and one for SQL Alchemy.